# Force min/max in Highcharts and avoid 0 for min

Tags: highcharts

I found many topics about how to force `min` but it still doesn't work in my case. This is my last chance. I use the latest Highcharts 4.0.1 version.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gu8Bs/. I want to avoid the `0` and force `1` instead because my chart is a ranking evolution. No matter the values are.

```
$('#chart').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
        labels: {
            rotation: 300,
            y: 20
        },
        categories: ["2014-03-24", "2014-03-25", "2014-03-26", "2014-03-27", "2014-03-28", "2014-03-29", "2014-03-30", "2014-03-31", "2014-04-01", "2014-04-02", "2014-04-03"]
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'linear',
        allowDecimals: false,
        reversed: true,
        min: 1,
        max: 300
    },
    series: [{
        "data": [270, 251, 246, 2, 3, 6, 13, 19, 30, 42, 57]
    }, {
        "data": [69, 64, 64, 1, 2, 4, 8, 11, 15, 16, 25]
    }],
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    }
});
```

`min: 1` shows `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **[`tickPositioner`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositioner)**

```
yAxis: {
    type: 'linear',
    allowDecimals: false,
    reversed: true,
    min: 1,
    max: 300,
    tickPositioner: function () {
        var positions = [],
            tick = Math.floor(this.dataMin),
            increment = Math.ceil((this.dataMax - this.dataMin) / 6);

        for (; tick - increment <= this.dataMax; tick += increment) {
            positions.push(tick);
        }
        return positions;
    }
},
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/alirizaadiyahsi/gu8Bs/2/)**

**EDIT**

You can change it in these lines

```
tickPositioner: function () {
    var positions = [],

    // set starting position
    tick = 1; //Math.floor(this.dataMin),

    // set step size    
    increment = 50; //Math.ceil((this.dataMax - this.dataMin) / 6);

    for (; tick - increment <= this.dataMax; tick += increment) {
        if(tick == 1)
            tick 
        positions.push(tick);
        if(tick == 1)
            tick = 0;
    }
    return positions;
}
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/alirizaadiyahsi/gu8Bs/3/)**

Comment: Thank's it's almost perfect. What about keeping the yAxis labels: 50, 100, 150...?

Comment: If I have values < 25 I have 1-25 on yAxis instead of 1-300. Have you got a trick for this? This must fit any values actually. Thank's!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is just to set `tickPositions`, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gu8Bs/5/

```
yAxis: {
    type: 'linear',
    allowDecimals: false,
    reversed: true,
    tickPositions: [1, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300]
},
```

Comment: Well thought! I appreciate.

Comment: @sylouuu, this is the same with mine, but I create positions, dinamically, and you can improve the compution logic, and you can generate positions, that are as your expected...

Comment: Of course, you are right - your solution is much better, when your data is more dynamic. If you have always the same range, then `tickPositions` are better solution - easy to read, easy to change.